# Unable to run emulator in AMD Ryzen 5 system?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am very new to android development. I am using the android studio in AMD Ryzen 5 2500U system, but unable to run the emulator. I am sharing the details of my dev environment: 
1. Windows 10 Pro with Hyper-V enabled. 
2. Installed - Android Studio 3.6 Canary 4 
3. In Android Studio - installed virtual device: Nexus 5 API 25, Android 7.1.1, CPU x86. 
4. SDK Platform 25 with ARM 64 v8a system image.

Issue: My emulator runs for 2 seconds and stop working. Please help me to resolve the issue.